# ruby on rails app doesn't show my view's html code

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just create a new rails project and try to add new page. i write `rails g controller main index`, and its create only controller. I try to add in view a new folder named "main" and create file "index.html.erb", but when i try to see my page it just return nothing, a white page without html code
this is my main_controller.rb

`class MainController < ApplicationController def index end end`

this is my index.html.erb
`<p>hello</p>`

and this is my routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do root 'home#index' end
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the correct route as your controller is named MainController so your route should be "main#index". Your route file should have this code

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do 
 root 'main#index'
end
```

Check if you have a HomeController and if you don't have maybe it's just cached as it's showing blank page try clearing the cookies and reloading the page. (Works for me most of the times.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify correct controller in your `routes.rb` file which is `MainController`, so it should look like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do 
   root 'main#index'
end
```

Comment: It still unclear why the original would render a blank page instead of causing a routing error.